# Trying to build test-launch.c for gstreamer but fails to build

Tags: c++, makefile, gstreamer, rtsp, cflags

I am trying to build [test-launch.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/master/examples/test-launch.c) on my ubuntu machine (i5) with this command:

```
gcc -o test-launch test-launch.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0`
```

but it fails to build. The error message I see is the following:

```
test-launch.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_enable_rtcp'
```

I have already installed

- libgstrtspserver-1.0
- libgstreamer1.0-dev

I am pretty confused and I am wondering if anybody can help me :)

Thank you for reading !

I have the entire build log [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/4c031c8e).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of GStreamer do you have installed? According to the documentation `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_enable_rtcp()` is introduced with GStreamer 1.20 which has not yet been released.